# How to do a non-equi join in SQL with multiple time ranges per group?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm looking for a way to do a [non-equi join in SQL](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-non-equi-join.php), joining by whether col x from table A is within a range of dates given in col y from table B. However, table B has *multiple* possible ranges per ID, and the table's data format is *long*. For example:

```bash
# Table A
# | person_id | breakfast_date | fruit_eaten_for_breakfast |
# |-----------|----------------|---------------------------|
# | 1         | 2023-03-12     | banana                    |
# | 1         | 2023-03-25     | apple                     |
# | 1         | 2023-04-01     | orange                    |
# | 1         | 2023-04-05     | kiwi                      |
# | 1         | 2023-04-22     | grapefruit                |
# | 2         | 2024-12-15     | strawberry                |
# | 2         | 2024-01-11     | blueberry                 |
# | 2         | 2024-02-12     | mango                     |
# | 2         | 2024-02-29     | watermelon                |
# | 2         | 2024-03-10     | pear                      |


# Table B
# | person_id | period_start_and_end | period |
# |-----------|----------------------|--------|
# | 1         | 2023-03-15           | 1      | first period for user_id = 1 started
# | 1         | 2023-03-30           | 1      | on March 15 and ended on March 30.
# | 1         | 2023-04-02           | 2      |
# | 1         | 2023-04-10           | 2      |
# | 1         | 2023-04-12           | 3      |
# | 1         | 2023-04-20           | 3      |
# | 2         | 2024-01-01           | 1      |
# | 2         | 2024-01-05           | 1      |
# | 2         | 2024-02-10           | 2      | second period for user_id = 2 started
# | 2         | 2024-02-13           | 2      | on Feb 10 and ended on Feb 13.
```

Note about table B : each `person_id` could have one or many `period`s, and we cannot know – i.e., we're agnostic to – how many periods per person, when writing the SQL query.

### Expected Output

```bash
# | person_id | breakfast_date | fruit_eaten_for_breakfast | period |
# |-----------|----------------|---------------------------|--------|
# | 1         | 2023-03-25     | apple                     | 1      |
# | 1         | 2023-04-05     | kiwi                      | 2      |
# | 2         | 2024-02-12     | mango                     | 2      |
```

#### SQL Dialect

I work on AWS Athena that is based on Trino SQL.

##### Reproducible data

```sql
WITH

table_a AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, DATE('2023-03-12'), 'banana'),
    (1, DATE('2023-03-25'), 'apple'),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-01'), 'orange'),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-05'), 'kiwi'),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-22'), 'grapefruit'),
    (2, DATE('2024-12-15'), 'strawberry'),
    (2, DATE('2024-01-11'), 'blueberry'),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-12'), 'mango'),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-29'), 'watermelon'),
    (2, DATE('2024-03-10'), 'pear')
  ) AS t(person_id, breakfast_date, fruit_eaten_for_breakfast)
),

table_b AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, DATE('2023-03-15'), 1),
    (1, DATE('2023-03-30'), 1),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-02'), 2),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-10'), 2),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-12'), 3),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-20'), 3),
    (2, DATE('2024-01-01'), 1),
    (2, DATE('2024-01-05'), 1),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-10'), 2),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-13'), 2)
  ) AS t(person_id, period_start_and_end, period)
)
```

### What I have tried so far

Well, not much. The regular non-equi join procedure I'm familiar with has the start date in one column and the end date in another column. But in the current case, we have multiple periods per `person_id`, and more problematic – we don't know how many. So even if I "pivot" the table to wide format, I still don't know how to figure out the multiple and unknown periods per `person_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot table_b to get the time ranges, that you need to join to table_a

```
WITH

table_a AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, DATE('2023-03-12'), 'banana'),
    (1, DATE('2023-03-25'), 'apple'),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-01'), 'orange'),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-05'), 'kiwi'),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-22'), 'grapefruit'),
    (2, DATE('2024-12-15'), 'strawberry'),
    (2, DATE('2024-01-11'), 'blueberry'),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-12'), 'mango'),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-29'), 'watermelon'),
    (2, DATE('2024-03-10'), 'pear')
  ) AS t(person_id, breakfast_date, fruit_eaten_for_breakfast)
),

table_b AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, DATE('2023-03-15'), 1),
    (1, DATE('2023-03-30'), 1),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-02'), 2),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-10'), 2),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-12'), 3),
    (1, DATE('2023-04-20'), 3),
    (2, DATE('2024-01-01'), 1),
    (2, DATE('2024-01-05'), 1),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-10'), 2),
    (2, DATE('2024-02-13'), 2)
  ) AS t(person_id, period_start_and_end, period)
), table_b_pivot as (
SELECT person_id,MIN(period_start_and_end) from_date, MAX(period_start_and_end) as To_date, period FROM table_b
GROUP BY person_id, period)
SELECT table_a.person_id, breakfast_date, fruit_eaten_for_breakfast, period
FROM table_a JOIN table_b_pivot 
  ON table_a.breakfast_date BETWEEN table_b_pivot.from_date AND  table_b_pivot.To_date
AND table_a.person_id = table_b_pivot.person_id
ORDER BY table_a.person_id,period
```

| person_id | breakfast_date | fruit_eaten_for_breakfast | period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-25 | apple | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-04-05 | kiwi | 2 |
| 2 | 2024-02-12 | mango | 2 |